# mysql stored procedure question

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a credit and debit column.

I need to get the highest balance out of that, and I think a stored procedure is the way to do it, but I have no idea how.

I need to start with the first row, add the debits, subtract the credits and store the value A.

Second row is A+debit-credit=B; A = max(A,B)
Repeat last step till the end.

Remember, I'm looking for the highest EVER, not the current, which would just be
sum(debit-credit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you'd want the running total to be `A+credit-debit` but switch them if needed.

```
SET @balance := 0;
SET @high := 0;
SELECT @high := GREATEST(@balance := @balance+credit-debit, @high) FROM mytable;
SELECT @high;
```

**edit:**  In response to your comment about forming a stored function from this... unlike stored procedures, stored functions must return one value, so they can't contain a `SELECT` query unless the query stores its result in a variable.  This means the query must be guaranteed to have a single-value result.  Below is a function I got to work, because in this case you only want the MAX value of `@high` anyway:

```
CREATE FUNCTION high_bal() RETURNS DECIMAL
BEGIN
  SET @balance := 0;
  SET @high := 0;

  SELECT MAX(@high := GREATEST(@balance := @balance+debit_acc-credit_acc, @high))
  INTO @high
  FROM credit_acc where credit_used_acc=63395;

  RETURN @high;
END$$
```

Comment: That did the job, but I'm having trouble making it a procedure, see below.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I thought I was going to be smart and make it a function, because I only want one value as the result...

DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `cc`.`high_bal`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `cc`.`high_bal`()
    RETURNS DECIMAL

```
BEGIN
SET @balance := 0;
SET @high := 0;
SELECT @high := GREATEST(@balance := @balance+debit_acc-credit_acc, @high) FROM credit_acc where credit_used_acc=63395;

RETURN @high;
END$$

print("code sample");

DELIMITER ;
```

But that gives me  the error "
Not allowed to return a result set from a function" Which I don't understand because I do just want the single value.

Answer (score 0):

User Defined Functions are only things that you embed within an SQL statement. They operate in the context of each single row (e.g. 40 rows, the function is executed 40 times). If you want an aggregate from a set (multiple rows), you use an SQL statement with an aggregate function in it (e.g. MAX(columname)). And that returns a "result set", which happens to be one row with one value.

Answer (score -1):

May

```
select max(debit-credit) from yourtable
```

work?

Try to test it.

Comment: No, all this does is give me the highest single charge ever made, it doesn't consider what the balance is after that charge was made.